# how to target first child of active item in multiple carausel

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a multiple carausel which slide one item at a time. I am cloning my carausel item .Now i want to add class selected in the first children of active class.

I am using https://www.bootply.com/HNtK6pWwFp#, but convert it for bootstrap 4 already.

I tried

```
  $('.carousel-control-next-icon').click(function () {
     alert("next icon clicked");
   $(".carousel-item.active.children(:first-child)").addClass('selected');
  });
```

and also try to play with dom, but didn't get any success.

selected class has border style.i added selected class with first item. and later i am using removeClass and addClass.If need more info, i am happy to load more code.

Comment: Where's the "converted to Bootstrap 4" carousel?

Comment: `$("#vertical-slide-carousel .item.active").addClass('selected');` this way maybe?

Comment: @Zim.... I tried to add small segment of my carausel here-https://jsfiddle.net/nf438zts/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the click event, use the Carousel `slid` event with proper selector.

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(".carousel-item.active div:first-child").addClass('selected');
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/NYPTgKPjng

And, you don't really need the jQuery to add a class. You can just use a CSS selector like:

```
.carousel-item.active div:first-child {
    border: blue solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: Zim as i mentioned i played a lot with dom. but really not able to do this. can you please apply your changes in my fiddle, make it working there? thanks in advance